# how can i connect project to DB

Tags: c#, html, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I try run my app that made by visual studio 2012 on other device that dont have visual studio installed. but it show this message:

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application.
>
> If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and
>   attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will close
>   immediately.  A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a
>   Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is
>   properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is
>   enabled.).

Comment: In your app you have defined a connection string to the Sql database on your machine. When you move the app to another machine, that db cannot be found. It has nothing to do with VS installed but only with the missing DB.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's trying to connect to a database and failing. If you're lucky, then there is a .config file file with the exe. Have a look in that and see if there is anything that looks like a connection string. If there is, change it to point to the database that you need it to connect to.

If there isn't a .config file, or it doesn't have a connection string, then it's probably hard-coded into the program and you're out of luck...

Good Luck!

Comment: you know? it work properly on my device that visual studio 2012 installed on it but it dos not work on others! how can i edit connection string and fix this problem?

Comment: Have you found the config file?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to see if the device you are running if from has acces to the sql db. Sound to me like it might be a permission problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your server hostname for `Data Source` parameter in SQL Connection String.

Try This:

```
String ConnectionString="Data Source=yourServerHostName;Initial Catalog=databasename;UID=username;PWD=password;Integrated Security=True;"
```